# Selecting duplicated classes with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, selector

1 Class duplicated in html 9 times and my question is how can select duplicated classes with css? Solutions?

```
<li class="its"></li>
<li class="its"></li>
<li class="its"></li>
<li class="its"></li>
<li class="its"></li>
<li class="its"></li>
<li class="its"></li>
<li class="its"></li>
<li class="its"></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LMnK4/

Comment: What do you mean by "selecting duplicated classes"? Select all of them, or select them individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set an id to an element to identify it

```
<li id="unique-element" class="its"></li>
<li id="another-element" class="its"></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jose - Classes are meant for grouping where it can be given n number of times to different tags where as the ID is unique. You can specify a tag with only 1 unique ID.

```
<li id="first-element" class="its"></li>
<li id="second-element" class="its"></li>
<li id="third-element" class="its"></li>
```

Answer for your post - Make the first element class to original and the other classes to duplicate.

```
<li id="first-element" class="original"></li>
<li id="second-element" class="duplicate"></li>
<li id="third-element" class="duplicate"></li>
<li id="third-element" class="duplicate"></li>
```

To apply CSS rules -

Classes can be selected like this `.its {CSS STYLING INSIDE THE BRACKET}`.

Note : CSS Applied using class will be applied to all the elements with the respective class.

ID's can be selected like this `#first-element{CSS STYLING INSIDE THE BRACKET}`.

As the ID's are unique it'll be applied only to the respective tag.

[**More Info on HTML**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)

[**More Info on CSS**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to identify what your talking about, so I updated your fiddle.  jQuery is going to be the way to go if you want to do actual selecting of multiple items like that.

I did a little bit of modifications to give you a visual example of whats going on.

[A fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMnK4/2/)

I made it with a button so when it's clicked, it selects the LI's by the class name and adds a secondary class to them, giving them a font color change.

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
    $( "li" ).each(function() {
        $( this ).addClass( "foo" );
    });
});
```

---Edit---

If you indulge us with more information of what your actually wanting to do, and possibly any codes that you have tried, then we can help you a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath on the console to verify that the class is referenced more than once:

```
$x('//*[@class="its"][2]')
```

Use XPath to see which elements use duplicate class references:

```
$x('//li[@class][2]/@class')
```

Supported in Firefox or Chrome. IE does not support `$x` in its console API.

Once you've found that, use a library such as the [jQuery XPath Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/xpath/) to integrate in your code.

**References**

- [Firefox Web Console: The Command Line Interpreter - Helper Commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Helper_commands)
- [Chromium Command Line API Reference](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api)
- [Opera Dragonfly commandtransformer.js](https://github.com/operasoftware/dragonfly/blob/master/src/repl/commandtransformer.js#L267)
- [F12 developer tools console API methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265020)
- [W3C: XPath Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [W3C: Selectors Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/)